# Will the Mad Catz Portable Drum Kit pedal work with RB 3 drums?

Tags: rock-band-3

The title kinda says it all-- I was thinking about getting a Portable Drum Kit for my Xbox, and was surprised to see lots of praise for the kick drum pedal that comes with it. If I get it, can I use that as a second pedal with my RB3 drums?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes.   A good friend of mine has tested this for me as he purchased the same kit.   Just remember to plug the pedal in!